# How do I prove that if a sequence is divergent, its square can't be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I mean,
If {$a_n$} is divergent, can {$a_n^2$} be convergent? 
I believe that it can't be convergent, so I need to prove it.

Comment: Do you really mean series?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i meant sequence, sorry

Comment: Your claim is true for *nonnegative* sequences (because $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is continuous), but false in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Do it by your self.

If you are looking for the series, then consider the series with general term $n^{-1}$ and $n^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = (-1)^n$. We know that this sequence diverges. However, $a_n^2 = 1$, which obviously converges.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if a sequence is divergent doesn't mean that its limit to infinity is + of - infinity?

Comment: @Andarrkor A sequence is divergent if it does not converge. Diverging to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ are two particular ways this can happen, but they are not the only ways, as this example shows.

Comment: Actually this sequence is a bounded sequence. If the sequence is not converges then it is known as divergent sequence.

Comment: @Bungo Ok, understood. And what happens with {$a_n^2$} if I define that {$a_n$} converges to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?